# How to pass value from promoted class to the Ui_MainWindow()

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlabel

At first, I have followed this ([Painting in a QLabel with paintEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51768266/painting-in-a-qlabel-with-paintevent)) and I managed to get the snipping event in the desired qlabel. However, how do I get the self.begin and self.end value then pass and show to the other label initialized in class Ui_MainWindow.

I generated the .ui from qt designer and promote Labella.py to the certain label. Then I convert .ui to .py using pyuic.

In def setupUi I attached self.Tab2_PB_ButtonSnipping.clicked.connect(self.lockRegion) and in the def lockRegion, I want to get the value of the x and y of self.begin and self.end of the Labella.py, then display it in another label.

Comment: provide a [MRE]

Comment: You should be able to get the coordinates via `self.label.begin.x()`, `self.label.begin.y()`, etc.